# How to show array of array json in tableview using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Now my ViewController code is here -

```
import UIKit
struct jsonstruct: Codable {
    let name: String
    let meta_data: [Categories]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case meta_data
    }
}

struct Categories: Codable {
    let value: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var arrdata : [jsonstruct] = [jsonstruct]()
    var categorydata : [Categories] = [Categories]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        getdata()
    }
    
    func getdata() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://mywebstaging.net/ab/garnier/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=<key>&consumer_secret=<secret>")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            do{if error == nil{
                self.arrdata = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct].self, from: data!)
                print(self.arrdata)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }catch{
                print("Error in get json data")
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           if tableView == tableView {
            return arrdata.count
           }else{
            return categorydata.count
           }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            if tableView == tableView {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
                let getdata = arrdata[indexPath.row]
                cell.lblid.text = getdata.name
                return cell
            }
            else{
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
                let getdatadesciption = self.categorydata[indexPath.row]
                cell.lblname.text = getdatadesciption.value
                return cell
            }
        }
}
```

Hare only the "name" is being displayed in the tableview. But the "value" is not coming. The output I'm getting like this. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Remove every `if tableView == tableView {` it's only 1 table in your vc so the else will never trigger

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
        if tableView == tableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
            let getdata = arrdata[indexPath.row]
            cell.lblid.text = getdata.name
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
            let getdatadesciption = self.categorydata[indexPath.row]
            cell.lblname.text = getdatadesciption.value
            return cell
        }
```

with  `getdata.meta_data.first?.value` contains top category name

```
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
            let getdata = arrdata[indexPath.row]
            cell.lblid.text = getdata.name  
            cell.lblname.text = getdata.meta_data.first?.value
            return cell
```

You don't have to maintain 2 arrays it's only one

Comment: thank you so much! I was struggling with this for long. You really helped me a lottt!

Comment: And please help me a little more! I am trying to fetch images from the same json. images has been fetched successfully in tableview. But issue is coming in the "didSelectRowAt" part.  As follows :

Comment: I have used this extension : extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImage(from url: String) {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
}

Comment: cell?.img.downloadImage(from: (self.arrdata[indexPath.item].images.first?.src)!)        --- it has shown me output in cellforrowat part

Comment: detail?.Image.downloadImage(from: (self.arrdata[indexPath.item].images.first?.src)!).  --- but it is showing me error in disselectrowat part. plz help!

Comment: try to print `self.arrdata[indexPath.item].images.first?.src` may be it's invalid

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if tableView == tableView {
                return arrdata.count
            } else {
                return categorydata.count
            }
        }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == tableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
            let getdata = arrdata[indexPath.row]
            cell.lblid.text = getdata.name
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
            let getdatadesciption = self.categorydata[indexPath.row]
            cell.lblname.text = getdatadesciption.value
            return cell
        }
    }
```

With

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrdata.count
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell
        let data = arrdata[indexPath.row]
        let category = data.meta_data.first
        cell.lblid.text = data.name
        cell.lblname.text = category.value
        return cell
    }
```